# Nginx can't serve static file from home directory

Tags: nginx

I have a `index.html` file in both locations `/home/ubuntu/web/build` and `/var/www/html`

There is no other complicated rules.

However only `root /var/www/html` works!

```
        # root /home/ubuntu/web/build; fails!
        root /var/www/html; # works!
        index index.html;


        location / {
                autoindex on;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

Here are the permissions

```
f: /var/www/html
 drwxr-xr-x root root /
 drwxr-xr-x root root var
 drwxr-xr-x root root www
 drwxr-xr-x root root html

f: /home/ubuntu/web/build
 drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
 drwxr-xr-x root   root   home
 drwxr-x--- ubuntu ubuntu ubuntu
 drwxrwxr-x ubuntu ubuntu web
 drwxrwxr-x ubuntu ubuntu build
```

Comment: The user which runs Nginx needs to have read access to every directory in the path. I can see that the `ubuntu` folder is only accessible by the `ubuntu` user and the `ubuntu` group.

Answer (score 4):

Nginx runs as `nginx` user, hence it should have read permissions to all the directories in the path. `/home/ubuntu` is owned by the `ubuntu` user and `ubuntu` group, so the third group of permisisons (because `nginx` user is not in the `ubuntu` group`) describes access to the directory. There are two solutions:

- Add read permissions to all users to the `/home/ubuntu` directory (not recommended)
- Add `nginx` user to `ubuntu` group

  - `sudo usermod -aG ubuntu www-data`

    - `usermod`: This command is used to modify user account properties.
    - `aG`: The -a flag appends the user to the group without removing them from their current groups.
    - The `-G` flag specifies the group to which you want to add the user.
      ubuntu: Replace this with the name of the group you want to add the Nginx user to.
    - `www-data`: This is the Nginx user's name on most Ubuntu systems. If your system uses a different username for Nginx, replace it accordingly.

Comment: ....and you'll also need to apply any relevant MAC permissions - i.e. for SELinux on RHEL and derivatives, Apparmor on Ubuntu and others.